# Word macro variable in hebrew

Tags: vba, ms-word, hebrew

I encounter a problem with Microsoft visual basic that variable values in Hebrew are converting to gibberish.
Please see the attach picture
[image: In the pic the variable immediately after the initialization]
The computer locale is Hebrew/ win 11

Why? what can I do to solve it ?
Thank you

Comment: If you write the variable to Word page is it still gibberish or is this just a display issue?

Comment: don, t jnow why, but suddenly every thing works fine...